# Difficulties in debugging on ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, debugging, device

I use Mac OS 10.7 and xcode 4.4.1 install in Virtualbox for Windows. I built an app and it runs ok on the xcode simulator. Then I archive to the ".ipa" file to install on my iPad. The app have 4 buttons. Everything is ok on the simulator but on the iPad, when I touch to the app and touch the first two button, it suddenly crash the app and kick me out to the main screen. My iPad used iOS 7.1 and the deployment target is 4.3. Has anyone know the problems? I already check the crash log of my iPad and this is what I got. Thanks a lot!

```
{"name":"TopUp","bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1 (11D201)","bundleID":"me.ios.vnpt.Topup","version":"1.0 (1.0)","app_name":"TopUp"}
Incident Identifier: BA7E8EF4-88A9-4EF9-86CB-92C80A9A5930
CrashReporter Key:   301e6c651d64cc8b3540e1b744da316a8b01afbc
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:             TopUp [1076]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/EB301C30-3E09-43B2-A0FF-4D65D4856339/TopUp.app/TopUp
Identifier:          me.ios.vnpt.Topup
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-20 15:35:44.637 +0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2e020fce 0x38ccccca 0x2e020f10 0x30babd70 0x30b04626 0x30960be8 0x30841308 0x30841284 0x308ea932 0x309274ae 0x30925de6 0x30924e50 0x30b07ca6 0xa157a 0x30872052 0x30871ff2 0x30871fcc 0x3085d732 0x30871a4a 0x3087171c 0x3086c6e6 0x308418e8 0x3083ff92 0x2dfec256 0x2dfeb726 0x2dfe9f1a 0x2df54f0a 0x2df54cee 0x32e8765e 0x308a0168 0xa041a 0xa03b4)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3928f1f0 0x3927c000 + 78320
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f9792 0x392f6000 + 14226
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3923ffd8 0x391f7000 + 298968
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3856ecd2 0x3856e000 + 3282
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x385876e0 0x3856e000 + 104160
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38cccf62 0x38cc9000 + 16226
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x385851c4 0x3856e000 + 94660
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38584d28 0x3856e000 + 93480
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38ccce12 0x38cc9000 + 15890
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2df54f80 0x2df4d000 + 32640
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2df54cee 0x2df4d000 + 31982
11  GraphicsServices                0x32e8765e 0x32e7e000 + 38494
12  UIKit                           0x308a0168 0x30832000 + 450920
13  TopUp                           0x000a041a 0x9f000 + 5146
14  TopUp                           0x000a03b4 0x9f000 + 5044

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3927c808 0x3927c000 + 2056
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x391be078 0x391b3000 + 45176
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x391bddfe 0x391b3000 + 44542

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3928fc70 0x3927c000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f6bda 0x392f6000 + 3034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f6a94 0x392f6000 + 2708

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3927ca58 0x3927c000 + 2648
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3927c854 0x3927c000 + 2132
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dfeb896 0x2df4d000 + 649366
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dfe9fbc 0x2df4d000 + 643004
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2df54f0a 0x2df4d000 + 32522
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2df54cee 0x2df4d000 + 31982
6   WebCore                         0x364b7116 0x363f9000 + 778518
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f8916 0x392f6000 + 10518
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f8886 0x392f6000 + 10374
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f6aa0 0x392f6000 + 2720

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3928fc70 0x3927c000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f6bda 0x392f6000 + 3034
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x392f6a94 0x392f6000 + 2708

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b28318c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d615a4
r8: 0x17eb1d20    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d61598      lr: 0x392f9797      pc: 0x3928f1f0
cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: The crash log is somewhat useless if you can't see the symbols. You have to either symbolicate the crashlog or build directly to your device, in which case you will get a lot more info in Xcode.

Comment: I try to connect iPad to the xcode in Virtual box but that didn't work. so any suggestion for solution?

Comment: Like I said, you can resymbolicate the crash log to see what the issue is, but the bottom line is you're going to have a bad time building an app if you can't build to the device (assuming you have a paid developer account).

Comment: I think the problem is the older SDK of your app when you run on device with iOS7.It will work ok if OS of your device is lower than iOS 7.

Comment: Pretty much all bets are off when you're using old dev tools in an environment that their creators never tested on and are violating several software license agreements.  I imagine Apple will not be rushing to help you.  If your time actually has any appreciable value, spending money on hardware is a good investment.

Comment: I think the minimum expectation here for getting any help is a symbolicated crash report.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write iOS software effectively inside a virtual machine. It's a waste of time to even attempt it.

You need to either buy a mac, even a secondhand older one is fine, or else install OS X natively on your PC instead of inside VirtualBox.